# Correct aproach to find eigenvectors via eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $F=        \begin{bmatrix}
        -1 & -2 & 2 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$ be a matrix of a linear transformation $f:\mathbb{R^3}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$.
Find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues for $F$.

Solving the $det(F-\lambda I)=0$ I get that $\lambda_{1}=\lambda_{2}=1,\lambda_{3}=-1$

For $\lambda_{1}=1$
the matrix $F-I$ looks like this
\begin{bmatrix}-2 & -2 & 2 \\0 & 0 & 0 \ \\0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
The equivalent system for this matrix would be

$-2x - 2y + 2z = 0$

Because $-2$ is the pivot which goes to $x$ I represent $x$ via $y,z$ so that $N(F-\lambda I)= L=(\begin{bmatrix}-1 \\1 \\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\0 \\1\end{bmatrix})$ ?

Is that aproach correct?
I always represent the variables which multiply with the pivot via others?

Comment: eigenvalues  are  $1$,$0$,$0$

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking: you're aware of the fact that if you reduce a matrix then you most probably change its eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Comment: @datodatuashvili I've changed the question so that it represents the original problem

Comment: @DonAntonio I'm asking does it matter which of these variables $x,y,z$ will be the represented via the other two

Comment: @DraganZrilić Very weird way to ask, as your question is fact is about systes of linear equations and eigenvalues have no much business here, but anyway: the line below "The equivalent system for this matrix..." is wrong, as it should be $\;-2x-2y+2z=0\;$ , yet your linearly independent vectors, somehow, are correct

Comment: @DonAntonio Sorry,it was a typo.Anyway, in this case, can I only represent $x$ via $y,z$ because x is multiplied with the pivot $-2$?

Comment: @DraganZrilić No. Since you have one single equation with three unknowns. you can choose **any two of them** as parameters and then express the thrid one as a combination of the first two. You could as well have written $\;z=-x+y\;$ and etc. The final solution, of course, will be a basis for the very same eigenspace.

Comment: @DonAntonio Thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes (and this has nothing in particular to do with eigenvalues) when solving a linear system brought into row echelon form, the columns with a pivot correspond to the variables whose values are going to be determined by that equation; the columns without pivot are the variables whose values are chosen freely before this, and which serve as parameters for the solution. In your case you did not do much to get the system into row echelon form, so you are spoiled for choice of the pivot; however if you decide it is the initial term $-2x$ in the equation that is the pivot, then $y,z$ are parameters of the solution, and $x$ is determined by the equation. To get a basis of solutions, fix the parameters respectively to each column of the identity matrix, here $y=1,z=0$ respectively $y=0,z=1$, as you have done, giving the indicated vectors.

It should be noted that having $2$ independent eigenvectors for a double eigenvalue is quite exceptional; it would have been *much* more likely to find a system of rank$~2$ with only one independent solution. But people who make these exercises tend to have a strong preference for the diagonalisable case, which causes such extremely unlikely cases to often pop up in practical exercices.

Comment: So I couldn't solve the system like this $y=z-x$ and then use that solution to find the base vectors?

Comment: Certainly you could. You would get a different basis for the eigenspace, namely $(1,-1,0)$, $(0,1,1)$, but that is fine.

Comment: thank you for the explanation